# Oracle java not appearing in SDKMAN?

Tags: java, sdkman

```
s@s:~$ sdk ls java
================================================================================
Available Java Versions
================================================================================
 13.ea.18-open       10.0.2-zulu                                            
 12.0.1-sapmchn      10.0.2-open                                            
 12.0.1-zulu         9.0.7-zulu                                             
 12.0.1-open         9.0.4-open                                             
 12.0.1.j9-adpt      8.0.212-zulu                                           
 12.0.1.hs-adpt      8.0.212-amzn                                           
 12.0.1-librca   > * 8.0.212.j9-adpt                                        
 11.0.3-sapmchn      8.0.212.hs-adpt                                        
 11.0.3-zulu         8.0.212-librca                                         
 11.0.3-amzn         8.0.202-zulufx                                         
 11.0.3.j9-adpt      7.0.222-zulu                                           
 11.0.3.hs-adpt      6.0.119-zulu                                           
 11.0.3-librca       1.0.0-rc-16-grl                                        
 11.0.2-open         1.0.0-rc-15-grl                                        
 11.0.2-zulufx       1.0.0-rc-14-grl
```

Why is it missing ORACLE java 8? I need it to test something, and it's available on my other PC, so I'm wondering what the problem could be.

Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: All SDKMAN available Java versions can be viewed here: https://api.sdkman.io/2/candidates/java/linux/versions/list?installed=

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is no longer supported. This is the [github issue](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/543) for more information.

As the writer said:

> The reason that we're moving to OpenJDK is that Oracle doesn't provide
>   Docker images that are deemed official to Docker, whereas it appears
>   that OpenJDK ones are as shown there. So if we're going to deploy with
>   OpenJDK, then we'd like to match our local dev environment as well.

Comment: Interesting i could install it a month ago if that issue is from 2017

Comment: @user3761308 look at the last comment in the issue which is for 5 days ago which said: "Oracle JDK 8 has finally been pulled from SDKMAN due to it's
licensing. Use the OpenJDK instead."

Comment: SDKMAN v5.7.4+362 doesn't list OpenJDK Java 8 neither anymore . . :/

Comment: Oracle JDK versions are listed now